Copying a select/option list to another select/option list
I have a form where the user can select one of seven days for each of eight events. I found code that should let me copy the dates from one select to another, but it deletes and moves every other option to the new select dropdown instead of copying the entire list of options.


var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
toSelect.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++) {
  toSelect.appendChild(fromSelect.options[i]);
}
<div>
  <select id="Sel1">
    <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
    <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
    <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
    <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
    <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
    <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
    <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Sel2"></select>
</div>




I think what you're expecting here is .appendChild inserting the child nodes (the fromSelect.options[i]) into some "child node list". It's confusing: why are the nodes mysteriously vanishing?
When you use .appendChild, what actually is happening is that the parent of the child node is being set to the parent node. In other words, parent.appendChild(child) is the inverse of child.setParent(parent). The fix for this, then, is to clone the node before setting the child of the parent.
var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
toSelect.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++)
{
    var clone = fromSelect.options[i].cloneNode(true);
    toSelect.appendChild(clone);
}


You need to use cloneNode to create copy of original select options.


var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
toSelect.innerHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++) {
  toSelect.appendChild(fromSelect.options[i].cloneNode(true));
}
<div>
  <select id="Sel1">
    <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
    <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
    <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
    <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
    <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
    <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
    <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Sel2"></select>
</div>




no need for a loop here. if you want two exact same options you can pass the innerHTML of first select box to the second one.
<script>
    var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
    var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
    toSelect.innerHTML = fromSelect.innerHTML
</script>


You just need to loop through the options in reverse:
for (var i = fromSelect.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

You can run the snippet to see it working:


<div>
<select id="Sel1">
  <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
  <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
  <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
  <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
  <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
  <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
  <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
</select>
<select id="Sel2"></select>
</div>


<script>
var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
toSelect.innerHTML = "";
// for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++)
for (var i = fromSelect.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  toSelect.appendChild(fromSelect.options[i]);
}
</script>




You must append all options of formSelect to toSelect :


 var fromSelect = document.getElementById("Sel1");
        var toSelect = document.getElementById("Sel2");
        toSelect.innerHTML = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < fromSelect.options.length; i++) {
            var option = fromSelect.options[i].cloneNode(true);
            toSelect.appendChild(option);
        }
 <div>
        <select id="Sel1">
            <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
            <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
            <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
            <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
            <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
            <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
            <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
        </select>
    <select id="Sel2"></select>
</div>




The select element is a bit special compared to other HTML elements in that it has a list of it's options (options property) and the add() method. You can use them in combination with the cloneNode() method to copy all the options.


const form = document.forms.form01;

[...form.Sel1.options].forEach(option => {
  let clone = option.cloneNode(true);
  form.Sel2.add(clone);
});

// more or less a one-liner:
//[...form.Sel1.options].forEach(opt => form.Sel2.add(opt.cloneNode(true)));
<form name="form01">
  <select name="Sel1">
    <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
    <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
    <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
    <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
    <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
    <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
    <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
  </select>
  <select name="Sel2"></select>
</form>




Why not simply this?


Sel2.innerHTML = Sel1.innerHTML;
<div>
  <select id="Sel1">
    <option value="1">06/01/24</option>
    <option value="2">06/02/24</option>
    <option value="3">06/03/24</option>
    <option value="4">06/04/24</option>
    <option value="5">06/05/24</option>
    <option value="6">06/06/24</option>
    <option value="7">06/07/24</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Sel2"></select>
</div>



